# How To Call get_search_query(); In Wordpress functions.php File?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to call search keyword in functions.php file and use it in an array but it is not being called.

It is called easily in search.php file and I am able to show it on search results page using

```
<?php $search_query = get_search_query(); ?>
<div align="center">
<h2>Search Results For "<?php echo $search_query ?>"</h2>
</div>
```

How to call `$search_query` or`get_search_query();` in functions.php file ?

Comment: What's your purpose? the end goal of that requirement?

Comment: i want to show search results using ajax and the function has been created by me in functions.php

Comment: When i try to use 's'=> $search_query , or 's' => get_search_query , in args , it is not working but 's'=>'bangalore' or 's'=>'chennai' is working

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-to-load-search-results/

Comment: it did not help
Whatever I am trying to achieve is that possible?

Comment: I would need to see how your ajax request work.

Comment: Should I communicate my problem in detail through email or chat?
It will be a great help to me.

Comment: it is a small problem , if you will look at it through email , it might help you to solve it easily.Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Simply update your question and add your code.